# Can't read my .avi file using java

Tags: java, netbeans

```
try {
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("‪‪‪D:\\myJAVA\\javasbc\\SchoolBell.avi"));
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(audioInputStream);
    clip.start();
  } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

i got this exception.......

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ‪‪‪D:\myJAVA\javasbc\SchoolBell.avi (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

i copied the exact location of that file but it is still this exception occurr

Comment: You're not catching FileNotFoundException or any generic Exception, so how is it you're seeing this message?

Comment: Because In catch IOException present.

Comment: Maybe you don't have permission to read files from that directory

Comment: Actually it's not the only file the i load from that directory there is also a .txt file and that .txt successfully read by the program

Comment: i tried diffrent audio formats like .mp3, .avi, .mov and .wav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emm... the question is quite unclear

Anyways, as a guess, maybe the file path syntax is really "not correct" or the file does not exist; So please try

**A)** not to use "\\" directory but to use `File.separator` to avoid system dependant paths styles

**B)** or you may try to write a code which analyses is the path folders really exist? Something like this :

```
void myMethod(){
  final String VOLUME="D:";
  final String DIRECTORY_A_PATH=VOLUME+File.separator+"myJAVA";
  final String DIRECTORY_B_PATH=DIRECTORY_A_PATH+File.seperator+"javasbc";
  final String FILE_PATH=DIRECTORY_B_PATH+File.seperator+"SchoolBell.avi";

  File f0=new File(DIRECTORY_A_PATH);
  if(!f0.exists()){System.out.println(DIRECTORY_A_PATH+" does not exist");  

  return;
}

  File f1=new File(DIRECTORY_B_PATH);
  if(!f1.exists()){System.out.println(DIRECTORY_A_PATH+" does not exist"); 

  return;
}

  File f2=new File(FILE_PATH);
  if(!f2.exists()){System.out.println(FILE_PATH+" does not exist"); 
  return;
}



}
```

So you can analyze path before reading... Anyways Java is sensitive to cases so check upper and lower characters cases are all correct; Just one character may cause the exception

---

If you have more details please do comment

Good luck :)

Comment: thanks user390525. it works...